# Cosine Similarity Code (non-term vectors)

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

I am trying to find the cosine similarity between 2 vectors (x,y Points) and I am making some silly error that I cannot nail down. Pardone me am a newbie and sorry if I am making a very simple error (which I very likely am).

Thanks for your help

```
  public static double GetCosineSimilarity(List<Point> V1, List<Point> V2)
    {
        double sim = 0.0d;
        int N = 0;
        N = ((V2.Count < V1.Count)?V2.Count : V1.Count);
        double dotX = 0.0d; double dotY = 0.0d;
        double magX = 0.0d; double magY = 0.0d;
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
        {
            dotX += V1[n].X * V2[n].X;
            dotY += V1[n].Y * V2[n].Y;
            magX += Math.Pow(V1[n].X, 2);
            magY += Math.Pow(V1[n].Y, 2);
        }

        return (dotX + dotY)/(Math.Sqrt(magX) * Math.Sqrt(magY));
    }
```

Edit: Apart from syntax, my question was also to do with the logical construct given I am dealing with Vectors of differing lengths. Also, how is the above generalizable to vectors of m dimensions. Thanks

Comment: You are getting mixed up with indices and X, Y. The index in each list should represent components (i.e. 0->x, 1->y, 2->z). The other way you would just have 2 points V1 and V2, each with an x and y, representing a 2-dimensional vector. You do not need both the index n and the .X and .Y

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are in 2-dimensions, then you can have vectors represented as `(V1.X, V1.Y)` and `(V2.X, V2.Y)`, then use

```
public static double GetCosineSimilarity(Point V1, Point V2) {
 return (V1.X*V2.X + V1.Y*V2.Y) 
         / ( Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow(V1.X,2)+Math.Pow(V1.Y,2))
             Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow(V2.X,2)+Math.Pow(V2.Y,2))
           );
}
```

If you are in higher dimensions then you can represent each vector as `List<double>`. So, in 4-dimensions the first vector would have components `V1 = (V1[0], V1[1], V1[2], V1[3])`.

```
public static double GetCosineSimilarity(List<double> V1, List<double> V2)
{
    int N = 0;
    N = ((V2.Count < V1.Count) ? V2.Count : V1.Count);
    double dot = 0.0d;
    double mag1 = 0.0d;
    double mag2 = 0.0d;
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        dot += V1[n] * V2[n];
        mag1 += Math.Pow(V1[n], 2);
        mag2 += Math.Pow(V2[n], 2);
    }

    return dot / (Math.Sqrt(mag1) * Math.Sqrt(mag2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! You have been of great help.

Answer (score 2):

### Update Dec 30, 2023

---

As pointed out by Bellarmine Head, the latest version of **Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Core** Nuget package (version 1.0.1) does **NOT** have a CosineSimilarity function anymore, **but** you can use the Microsoft static method in the **System.Numerics.Tensors** Nuget package [TensorPrimitives.CosineSimilarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.tensors.tensorprimitives.cosinesimilarity?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) instead.  It accepts two read only spans (ReadOnlySpan x, ReadOnlySpan y).

Using float arrays the usage looks something like this:

```cs
using System.Numerics.Tensors;

float[] vector1 = new[] { 0.018007852f, 0.031938456f, -0.046234965f, };
float[] vector2 = new[] { 0.01055384f, 0.0020128791f, 0.013548848f };
double result = TensorPrimitives.CosineSimilarity(vector1, vector2);

Console.WriteLine($"The result was: {result}");
```

The closer the result is to 1 the more similar the two items are.

### Older post

---

Microsoft has a extension method in the **Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Core** Nuget package (currently at version 1.0.0-beta1) that has extension method called [CosineSimilarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.semantickernel.ai.embeddings.vectoroperations.cosinesimilarityoperation.cosinesimilarity?view=semantic-kernel-dotnet).  It has three  overloads:

1. Array of number (float or double)
2. Span of T
3. ReadOnlySpan of T

Using float arrays the usage looks something like this:

```cs
float[] vector1 = new[] {  0.018007852f, 0.031938456f, -0.046234965f, };
float[] vector2 = new[] {  0.01055384f, 0.0020128791f, 0.013548848f };
double result = vector1.CosineSimilarity(vector2);
```

The closer the result is to 1 the more similar the two items are.

Comment: Now obsolete in SemanticKernel: `[Obsolete("Numerical operations will be removed in a future release. Use System.Numerics.Tensors.TensorPrimitives instead.")]`
Tensor version docs for cosine similarity:- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.tensors.tensorprimitives.cosinesimilarity?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#system-numerics-tensors-tensorprimitives-cosinesimilarity(system-readonlyspan((system-single))-system-readonlyspan((system-single)))

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be

```
return (dotX + dotY)/(Math.Sqrt(magX) * Math.Sqrt(magY))
```